# Certain .MOV video file will not play audio in VLC for iOS (iPad)

Tags: ios, vlc

I have tried 2 different iPads. Both have about 7 or 8 other .MOV files (from the same folder) that play just fine. However, this single .MOV file just will not output any audio. It plays fine on the PC (Windows 7). Should I just to convert it to a different video format or what? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to convert the .MOV file to a .MP4 file with Handbrake and audio is working now.